# Python decorator not executing

Tags: python, decorator

I am working on a decorator to register functions easier in my app, so I made a "do twice" decorator to test if i understood decorators correctly. I tried doing it, but it didn't work. Could someone help me?

My code (decorator.py):

```py
def do_twice(func):
    def wrapper_do_twice():
        func()
        func()
    return wrapper_do_twice
```

My code (main.py):

```py
from decorator import do_twice


@do_twice
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")
```

I expected the function to `say_whee()` to be executed twice and give the output

```
Whee! 
Whee!
```

But there was no output.

Comment: You don't show that you called your function. (btw your decorator looks fine)

Comment: You just forgot to call the function. Everything else is fine. Did you not type "say_whee()" at the end of your main.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your full main.py you never called the function `say_whee()`. You should call it afterwards either directly or in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block:

```py
from decorator import do_twice


@do_twice
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")

say_whee()
```

or

```py
from decorator import do_twice


@do_twice
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    say_whee()
```